# Convert Factor Date to integer

Tags: r

After reading in my csv, I have the date as a factor in the following format, dd-mm-yy (30-Dec-16). How can I convert the above to a readable date.

I've tried the following:

```
as.Date(DF$V1, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

and

```
as.Date(DF$V1, "%d/%b/%y")
```

Thanks,
S

Comment: This is probably a duplicate. However, this format will work: `as.Date("30-Dec-16", "%d-%b-%y")`.

Comment: `as.Date(as.character(DF$V1), "%d/%b/%y")`